# How integrate Quasar framework and Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, quasar-framework, quasar

How to install vuetify in a project generated with quasar cli?

In a normal project with vue cli only need the command

```
vue add vuetify
```

but in quasar cli I run the command

```
npm install vuetify
```

and generate new boot file, but i have an error in sass or sass-loader

Comment: Are you sure you want to use both in one project? I'm not sure, but it seems like Quasar provides superset of features in comparison w/ Vuetify. Q. looks like Vuetify + CLI tooling to me.

Answer (score 2):

He did it, but he's a bit of a cheater.
I needed a very fast migration to export a mobile app.
Steps:

1. Execute `quasar dev` at least once.
2. Enter `node_modules\@quasar\app\lib\generator.js` and change

   ```
   const paths = [
     'app.js',
     'client-entry.js',
     'client-prefetch.js',
     'import-quasar.js'
   ]
   ```

   by

   ```
     const paths = [
     'client-entry.js',
     'client-prefetch.js',
     'import-quasar.js'
   ]
   ```
3. Install vuetify  `npm install vuetify`
4. Enter `.quasar\app.js`  and put your vuetify configuration, in my case:

> ```
> import es from "vuetify/src/locale/es";
> import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
> import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
> const opts = {
>   theme: {
>     options: {
>       customProperties: true
>     },
>     themes: {
>       light: {
>         primary: "#F79DC2",
>         secondary: "#02283c",
>         accent: "#FFAB00",
>         error: "#a13835",
>         disabled: "#a13835",
>         background: "black"
>       }
>     }
>   },
>   lang: {
>     locales: { es },
>     current: "es"
>   }
> };
>
> Vue.use(Vuetify)
> ```

Below you have to add

> ```
> const vuetify = new Vuetify (opts)
>   const app = {
>     router,
>     store,
>     vuetify, <--------
>     render: h => h (App)
>   }
> ```

5. Enter App.vue and change the main div to

> ```
> <v-app id = "q-app">
>    .
>    .
> </v-app>
> ```

Working! I hope it works!

Comment: Hi @Vallemar, thanks for the description! How much increase in the delivered minified js did you experience after treeshaking?

Answer (score 1):

It, not a good idea to use two frontend UI frameworks like(bootstrap,vuetify, quasar ...) in one project, it's just like using honey and industrial sugar to make one tea.

### You should always consider the bundle size of your work.

*what if vuetify comes with a cli, would you have added vuetify to quasar or quasar to vuetify*

Comment: What if we only import the components that we need from each framework?

Answer (score 0):

how to connect/use Vuetify 3 in Quasar 2

Connecting Vuetify

1. `npm install vuetify`
2. create `src/ui/index.js`

```js
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/styles'

export const vuetifyInstance = createVuetify({/* ... */})
```

3. create `src/boot/registerVuetify.js`

```js
import { vuetifyInstance as vuetify } from 'src/ui'
export default ({ app }) => {
    app.use(vuetify)
}
```

add to `quasar.config.js`

```js
module.exports = configure(function (/*ctx*/) {
    return {
    //...
        boot: [
            //...
            '~src/boot/registerVuetify'
        ],
    //...
    }
})
```

4. exclude quasar UI framework (vite) =>
   add to `quasar.config.js`

```js
module.exports = configure(function( /*ctx*/ ) {
    return {
        //...
        build: {
            //...
            extendViteConf(viteConf) {
                viteConf.build.rollupOptions = {
                    output: {
                        // exclude quasar css framework (this does not completely exclude the framework from the final build)
                        manualChunks(path) {
                            if (/node_modules.*quasar/.test(path)) {
                                return null
                            }
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
            //...
            alias: {
                'quasar/dist/quasar.css': path.join(__dirname, './src/assets/sass/_your_styles.sass'),
            },
        },
        //...
        framework: {
             //...
             cssAddon: false,
             //...
        },
    }
})
```